# Big O of BubbleSort on a simple list of 5 values

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I believe that a BubbleSort is of the order O(n^2). As I read previous postings, this has to do with nested iteration. But when I dry run a simple unsorted list, (see below), I have the list sorted in 10 comparisons.

In my example, here is my list of integer values:
5  4  3  2  1

To get 5 into position, I did n-1 swap operations. (4)
To get 4 into position, I did n-2 swap operations. (3)
To get 3 into position, I did n-3 swap operations. (2)
To get 2 into position, I did n-4 swap operations. (1)

I can't see where (n^2) comes from, as when I have a list of n=5 items, I only need 10 swap operations.

BTW, I've seen (n-1).(n-1) which doesn't make sense  to me, as this would give 16 swap operations.

I'm only concerned with basic BubbleSort...a simple nested FOR loop, in the interest of simplicity and clarity.

Comment: The answer is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). I don't think this question belongs here, it might be answered thoroughly with examples at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: In your opinion, what is the meaning of "Big O" ? And what about "a" simple nested loop.

Comment: A measure of an algorithm's efficiency (with regards to number of operations to be performed) it gives a good estimate of performance with varying input sizes of n.

Comment: @ Tom, i've put together a small document of my understanding of Big(O). It's only several pages and I'm wondering if you would quickly view it. It's not a HW or anything, it's just my notes to aid my understanding so i'll not forget it. I found your previous posting useful, that's why i'm asking you.  No worries if you don't want to. Just thought i'd ask!  thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't seem to understand the concept of [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) very
well. It refers to how the number of operations or the time grows in
relation to the size of the input, *asymptotically, considering only the
fastest-growing term, and without considering the constant of
proportionality*.

A single measurement like your 5:10 result is completely meaningless.
Imagine looking for a function that maps 5 to 10. Is it 2N? N + 5? 4N –
10? 0.4N<sup>2</sup>? N<sup>2</sup> – 15? 4 log<sub>5</sub>N + 6? The
possibilities are limitless.

Instead, you have to analyze the algorithm to see how the number of
operations grows as N does, or measure the operations or time over many
runs, using various values of N and the most general datasets you can
devise. Note that your test case is not general at all: when checking
the average performance of a sorting algorithm, you want the input to be
in random order (the most likely case), not sorted or reverse-sorted.

Comment: interesting Tom, I understand the essence of what you're saying.

Comment: But the concept of O(n^2) best describing nested loops (like in BubbleSort) still evades me.  I guess its the mathematics behind (n-1)+(n-2)+(n-3)+(n-4)+(n-1) + 1 = (n-1)*(n-2) / 2  that I don't get

Comment: You have approximately n steps. Each step takes approximately n operations. Multiplying, and ignoring all but the fastest-growing term, you get n^2. Don't think in terms of (n-1)+(n-2). Think in terms of O(n), added n times, which is n*O(n), which is O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

If you wan to precise there are `(n)*(n-1)/2` operations because you are actually computing `n+(n-1)+(n-2)+...+1` as the first element needs `n` swaps, second element need `n-1` swaps and so on. So the algorithm is of `O(1/2 * (n^2) - n)` which in asymptotic notations is equal to `O(n^2)`. But what actually is happening in bubble sort is different. In bubble sort you perform a pass on array and swap the misplaced neighbors place, until there is no misplacement which means the array has become sorted. As each pass on array takes `O(n)` time and in the worst case you have to perform `n` passes so the algorithm is of `O(n^2)`. Note that we are counting the number of comparisons not the number of swaps.

There are two version of bubble sort mentioned in wikipedia:

```
procedure bubbleSort( A : list of sortable items )

   n = length(A)
   repeat 
     swapped = false
     for i = 1 to n-1 inclusive do
       /* if this pair is out of order */
       if A[i-1] > A[i] then
         /* swap them and remember something changed */
         swap( A[i-1], A[i] )
         swapped = true
       end if
     end for
   until not swapped
end procedure
```

This version perform `(n-1)*(n-1)` comparison -> `O(n^2)`

> **Optimizing bubble sort**
>   The bubble sort algorithm can be easily
>   optimized by observing that the n-th pass finds the n-th largest
>   element and puts it into its final place. So, the inner loop can avoid
>   looking at the last n-1 items when running for the n-th time:

```
procedure bubbleSort( A : list of sortable items )
    n = length(A)
    repeat
       swapped = false
       for i = 1 to n-1 inclusive do
          if A[i-1] > A[i] then
             swap(A[i-1], A[i])
             swapped = true
          end if
       end for
       n = n - 1
    until not swapped
end procedure
```

This version performs `(n-1)+(n-2)+(n-3)+...+1` operations which is `(n-1)(n-2)/2` comparisons -> `O(n^2)`

Comment: On 1st Swap I get:  [4 5] 3 2 1   Is this not counted as 1 comparison?

Comment: By end of 1st Pass, in total I will have made n-1 comparisons. I suppose I have to repeat this again for n-2 comparisons, n-3 comparisons, n-2 and finally n-1 comparisons. So total number of comparisons is (n-1)+(n-2)+(n-3)+(n-4)+(n-1) + 1. Which gets me back to 10.

Comment: As I said in the answer itself: `(n-1)+(n-2)+(n-3)+(n-4)+(n-1) + 1` = `(n-1)*(n-2) / 2` which is `O(n^2)`.  Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: Sorry, still not getting it.